# Java Timestamp to certain format

Tags: java

If I create a Java `Timestamp`:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(23423434);
```

And look at it with debugger I see it contains an object `cDate` with a `String` value `1970-01-01T08:30:23.000+0200`. Is that `String` some kind of certain format and if so how is it called? Also how can I print out this `String` from my `Timestamp`?

I have tried googling it but because I don't know what format it is I can't find the right keywords. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Found out that the format is called ISO 8601, but still cant figure out what's the safest way to create it from my `Timestamp`.

Comment: What you see in the debugger is the *string representation* of the `Timestamp` object. The actual data is most likely not stored as a string. If you could tell us *which* `Timestamp` class you're using (`java.security.Timestamp`, `java.sql.Timestamp` or some other) we might be able to tell you how to format its value as an ISO 8601 string.

Comment: are you talking about `java.security` or `java.sql` package?

Comment: Im using java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: Also, if it helps i can use Joda-Time library

Comment: @user1985273 Since it's a subclass of `java.util.Date` you should be able to find plenty of examples on the internet.

Comment: Joda Time is a good choice, as Java, especially in earlier versions, never did a good job of handling date and time.

Comment: Still doesn't, Tim :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i solved it usind Joda-Time like this:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(23423434);
DateTime datetime = new DateTime(timestamp).toString();
System.out.println(datetime.toString());
```

I had to use java.sql.Timestamp because it came from another part of the program i couldnt change.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Please show the include for Joda-Time and also for the `timestamp` so that it is clear which libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You have resolved your own question if this format is exactly you want.

Alternative, if you don't like the 'T' in the middle, you can simply `timpstamp.toString()` or directly use it as a `String` like in `System.out.println(timestamp)`. `Timestamp` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`, so it inherited many useful methods of the later.